# iPhone - Code of system sounds

Tags: iphone, system, audio

Do you know where I can find the list of constants that points to iOS system sounds, to make me able to give them to the AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from `AudioServices.h`:

```
//==================================================================================================
#pragma mark    AudioServices Constants

/*!
    @enum           AudioServices constants
    @abstract       Constants for use with System Sound portion of the AudioServices APIs.
    @constant       kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert 
                        Use this constant with the play sound APIs to
                        playback the alert sound selected by the User in System Preferences.
    @constant       kSystemSoundID_Vibrate
                        Use this constant with the play sound APIs to vibrate the device
                        - iPhone only 
                            - on a device with no vibration capability (like iPod Touch) this will 
                            do nothing
    @constant       kSystemSoundID_FlashScreen
                        Use this constant with the play sound APIs to flash the screen
                        - Desktop systems only
*/
enum
{
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    kSystemSoundID_Vibrate              = 0x00000FFF
#else
    kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert   = 0x00001000,
    kSystemSoundID_FlashScreen          = 0x00000FFE,
        // this has been renamed to be consistent
    kUserPreferredAlert     = kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert
#endif        
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but what about all these names we can find in the examples shown on the Web, like here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SysSound/Listings/Classes_SysSoundViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008018-Classes_SysSoundViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6

Comment: Which names are you referring to ?

Comment: "TAP" in -->     NSURL *tapSound   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"tap"

                                                withExtension: @"aif"];

 

    // Store the URL as a CFURLRef instance

    self.soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [tapSound retain];

 

    // Create a system sound object representing the sound file.

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (

    

        soundFileURLRef,

        &soundFileObject

    ); I found many others on web examples

Comment: tap is an resource added in the bundle of the app - SysSound. Its in the sounds folder under Resources - tap.aif

Answer (score 0):

The only one I'm aware of is `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate`, in AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h.